# C++/CLI How can I add a extension (a MFT), inside a library project

Tags: c++-cli, static-libraries, video-capture, visual-studio-extensions, ms-media-foundation

Usually to insert a MFT to my project I would simply just add the following code to the projects Package.appxmanifest file":

```
   <Extensions>
<Extension Category="windows.activatableClass.inProcessServer">
  <InProcessServer>
    <Path>ImagingEffects.WindowsPhone.dll</Path>
    <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="ImagingEffects.ImagingEffect" ThreadingModel="both" />
  </InProcessServer>
</Extension>
```

But my project does not contain the Package.appxmanifest file (I'm thinking this is because it is a static library). Is it possible to include my MFT into the library? (because I need to make a library function to start to record, take frames and process them.

Comment: You describe a DLL.  Seems very counter-productive to use a static library project.  Just don't.

Comment: Well yes, the extension that I need to add (inside my library) is a DLL, and well about the library I need to include the DLL inside, it's configuration is one of a static library, I am not allowed to change that. I just got the library project from the customer, need to add some features, and that's it.